# How do I compare two dictionaries in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary, compare

Is there an easy way to compare two `[String: AnyObject]` dictionaries in swift, since it doesn't accept the `==` operator?

By comparing two dictionaries, I mean checking that they have the same exact keys and for every key they have the same values.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

As already mentioned by Hot Licks you can use NSDictionary method [isEqualToDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/isEqualToDictionary:)() to check if they are equal as follow:

```
let dic1: [String: AnyObject] = ["key1": 100, "key2": 200]
let dic2: [String: AnyObject] = ["key1": 100, "key2": 200]
let dic3: [String: AnyObject] = ["key1": 100, "key2": 250]

println( NSDictionary(dictionary: dic1).isEqualToDictionary(dic2) )   // true
println( NSDictionary(dictionary: dic1).isEqualToDictionary(dic3) )  // false
```

you can also implement a custom operator "==" as follow:

```
public func ==(lhs: [String: AnyObject], rhs: [String: AnyObject] ) -> Bool {
    return NSDictionary(dictionary: lhs).isEqualToDictionary(rhs)
}

println(dic1 == dic2)   // true
println(dic1 == dic3)   // false
```

---

**Xcode 9 • Swift 4**

From the docs, dictionary is now defined as a struct:

```
struct Dictionary<Key : Hashable, Value> : Collection, ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral
```

> Description
>
> A collection whose elements are key-value pairs. A
>   dictionary is a type of hash table, providing fast access to the
>   entries it contains. Each entry in the table is identified using its
>   key, which is a hashable type such as a string or number. You use that
>   key to retrieve the corresponding value, which can be any object. In
>   other languages, similar data types are known as hashes or associated
>   arrays. Create a new dictionary by using a dictionary literal. A
>   dictionary literal is a comma-separated list of key-value pairs, in
>   which a colon separates each key from its associated value, surrounded
>   by square brackets. You can assign a dictionary literal to a variable
>   or constant or pass it to a function that expects a dictionary.

Here’s how you would create a dictionary of HTTP response codes and their related messages:

```
var responseMessages = [200: "OK",
                        403: "Access forbidden",
                        404: "File not found",
                        500: "Internal server error"]
```

> The responseMessages variable is inferred to have type `[Int: String]`.
>   The Key type of the dictionary is `Int`, and the Value type of the
>   dictionary is `String`.

To create a dictionary with no key-value pairs, use an empty dictionary literal ([:]).

```
var emptyDict: [String: String] = [:]
```

Any type that conforms to the Hashable protocol can be used as a dictionary’s Key type, including all of Swift’s basic types. You can use your own custom types as dictionary keys by making them conform to the Hashable protocol.

---

We don't need to define a custom operator anymore:

From the docs:

```
static func ==(lhs: [Key : Value], rhs: [Key : Value]) -> Bool
```

---

Testing:

```
let dic1 = ["key1": 100, "key2": 200]
let dic2 = ["key1": 100, "key2": 200]
let dic3 = ["key1": 100, "key2": 250]

print(dic1 == dic2)   // true
print(dic1 == dic3)   // false
```

In the example above all dictionary keys and values are the same type.
If we try to compare two dictionaries of type `[String: Any]` Xcode will complain that Binary operator == cannot be applied to two `[String: Any]` operands.

```
let dic4: [String: Any] = ["key1": 100, "key2": "200"]
let dic5: [String: Any] = ["key1": 100, "key2": "200"]
let dic6: [String: Any] = ["key1": 100, "key2": Date()]

print(dic4 == dic5)  // Binary operator == cannot be applied to two `[String: Any]` operands
```

But we can extend the `==` operator functionality implementing an infix operator, casting Swift Dictionary to NSDictionary and constraining the dictionary values to Hashable Protocol:

---

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

```
public func ==<K, L: Hashable, R: Hashable>(lhs: [K: L], rhs: [K: R] ) -> Bool {
   (lhs as NSDictionary).isEqual(to: rhs)
}
```

---

Testing:

```
let dic4: [String: AnyHashable] = ["key1": 100, "key2": "200"]
let dic5: [String: AnyHashable] = ["key1": 100, "key2": "200"]
let dic6: [String: AnyHashable] = ["key1": 100, "key2": Date()]
```

---

```
print(dic4 == dic5)   // true
print(dic4 == dic6)   // false
```

---

```
let dic7: [String: String] = [ "key2": "200"]
let dic8: [String: Date] = [ "key2": Date()]
print(dic7 == dic8)   // false
```

Comment: This looks like a great candidate for a Generic, a Protocol using Type constraints.

Answer (score 22):

#### Swift 4 Update:

Comparing Dictionaries is now native! (Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2430767))

---

#### Swift 3:

Leo Dabus already has an excellently written post with the accepted solution. However, for me, I found that it needed one more step to be fully usable. As you can see from his code, you need to set your dictionary type to `[AnyHashable: Any]`, or otherwise you'll get `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[String : Any]' operands`, to use a dictionary common in deserializing JSON for my example.

Generics to the rescue!:

```
// Swift 3.0
func == <K, V>(left: [K:V], right: [K:V]) -> Bool {
    return NSDictionary(dictionary: left).isEqual(to: right)
}
```

or in another case I had, with `[String: Any?]`:

```
func == <K, V>(left: [K:V?], right: [K:V?]) -> Bool {
    guard let left = left as? [K: V], let right = right as? [K: V] else { return false }
    return NSDictionary(dictionary: left).isEqual(to: right)
}
```

Comment: Where do I define this method?

Comment: This can be done anywhere, so I usually put it in a separate file, usually something like `Foundation+utils.swift` or the like. KIM, Swift 3 is not supported as of Xcode 10.2, so you most likely will not need this anymore. :bittersweet emotions: ;)

Answer (score 11):

In Swift 2, when **both `Key` and `Value`** are `Equatable`, you can use `==` on the dictionary itself:

```
public func ==<Key : Equatable, Value : Equatable>(lhs: [Key : Value], rhs: [Key : Value]) -> Bool
```

And, NSObject is Equatable:

```
public func ==(lhs: NSObject, rhs: NSObject) -> Bool
```

In your case, if you are working with Obj-C objects that you want to compare using `isEqual:`, you can simply use NSObject as your value type (rather than AnyObject).

Comment: unfortunately I am not using swift 2

Comment: You will be real soon, the release of iOS9 is imminent, in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Without custom type in value of Dictionary, in Swift 2+ you can use the `==` operator to compare two `Dictionary` to check if they are equal or not.

But in some cases with custom types as the `Dictionary`'s value (like `struct`), you must adopt `Equatable` in order for that custom type to use `==` operator.

Ex:

```
// custom type
struct Custom: Equatable {
    var value: Int
}

// MARK: adopting Equatable
func ==(lhs: Custom, rhs: Custom) -> Bool {
    if lhs.value == rhs.value {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `==` operator to compare two dictionaries:

```
let dic3: [String: Custom] = ["key1": Custom(value:1), "key2": Custom(value:2)]
let dic4: [String: Custom] = ["key1": Custom(value:1), "key2": Custom(value:2)]

if (dic3 == dic4) {
    print("equal")
} else {
    print("not equal")
}
```

Comment: why don't you just write `func == <Key: Equatable, Value: Equatable>(lhs: [Key, Value], rhs: [Key, Value])`?

Comment: @NoodleofDeath value of dictionary is not Equatable type. And I want to write function in Swift, that not depend on Cocoa Lib type (like NSObject, NSDictionary)