# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[AnyHashable:Any]!' operands

Tags: dictionary, swift3, binary-operators

I'm going to compare 2 dictionaries in this way:

```
var previouldObj:[AnyHashable:Any]!
var obj:[AnyHashable:Any]!
for i in 0..<self.arrayData.count
{

     obj=self.arrayData[i] as! [AnyHashable:Any]
     if(obj == previouldObj)
     {

     }
}
```

But I'm getting this error

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[AnyHashable:Any]!' operands

How to solve this? Please help me
Thanks

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365654/how-do-i-compare-two-dictionaries-in-swift

Comment: @UmairAfzal I tried that but where to put convenience init(dictionary otherDictionary: [AnyHashable : Any])?

Comment: why not use isEqualToDictionary() method ?

Comment: That method is not even coming up when type @UmairAfzal

Comment: public func ==(lhs: [String: AnyObject], rhs: [String: AnyObject] ) -> Bool {
    return NSDictionary(dictionary: lhs).isEqualToDictionary(rhs)
} is giving me various errors

Comment: comparing two Any values is virtually impossible. You have to downcast the values to something more specialized, most likely you have an idea, what the Any in your dictionary represents.

Comment: @UmairAfzal the solution there works, but NOT always. If the value which was stored as Any in the dictionary has a type which doesn't conform to AnyObject protocol or is not bridgeable to such a type,  comparing of two NSDictionaries will return false, even though there are identical copies of the same dictionary. That could be very hard to debug ...

Comment: @user3441734 is there any solution you know to compare these things. What about [String:Any] types?

Comment: @user1960169 to check equality of two values, the values must have the same type which conforms to Equatable protocol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147197/discussion-between-user1960169-and-user3441734).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to convert `previouldObj` into an `NSDictionary` and call `isEqual`.

```
    var previouldObj:[AnyHashable:Any]!
    var nsDict = NSDictionary(dictionary: previouldObj)
    var obj:[AnyHashable:Any]!
    for i in 0..<self.arrayData.count
    {

        obj=self.arrayData[i] as! [AnyHashable:Any]
        if(nsDict.isEqual(to: obj))
        {

        }
```

Comment: if(nsDict.isEqual(to: obj)==false)
                    {} but this always returns false. why is that. My array has so many equal dictionaries.. im trying to avoid the duplication by checking this condition. But I can't achive this