# How to compare 2 dictionaries in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift3, swift-dictionary

Hello I am getting duplicated Dictionaries from my service.

```
[{
DisplayName2 = "ABC";
Employee = "<null>";
EmployeeCode = 17227;
ImagePath = "/profile/image/759006c5e4214f0";
LeaveDetail = "<null>";
LeaveDetailLeaveDate = "2017-07-04T00:00:00";
LeaveEntry = "<null>";
LeaveEntryEndDate = "2017-07-04T00:00:00";
LeaveEntryNoOfDays = 1;
LeaveEntryStartDate = "2017-07-04T00:00:00";
LeaveEntryStartDateSession = FH;
LeaveType = "<null>";
LeaveTypeCode = 1;
LeaveTypeName = ANNUAL;
RequestStatus = C;
Shift = "<null>";
ShiftName = "";
SystemLeaveTypeCode = ANN;
TomorrowLeaveCount = 0;
```

},

```
{
DisplayName2 = "ABC";
Employee = "<null>";
EmployeeCode = 17227;
ImagePath = "/profile/image/759006c5e4214f0";
LeaveDetail = "<null>";
LeaveDetailLeaveDate = "2017-07-04T00:00:00";
LeaveEntry = "<null>";
LeaveEntryEndDate = "2017-07-04T00:00:00";
LeaveEntryNoOfDays = 1;
LeaveEntryStartDate = "2017-07-04T00:00:00";
LeaveEntryStartDateSession = FH;
LeaveType = "<null>";
LeaveTypeCode = 1;
LeaveTypeName = ANNUAL;
RequestStatus = C;
Shift = "<null>";
ShiftName = "";
SystemLeaveTypeCode = ANN;
TomorrowLeaveCount = 0;
```

},

```
{
DisplayName2 = "ABC";
Employee = "<null>";
EmployeeCode = 17227;
ImagePath = "/profile/image/759006c5e4214f0";
LeaveDetail = "<null>";
LeaveDetailLeaveDate = "2017-07-10T00:00:00";
LeaveEntry = "<null>";
LeaveEntryEndDate = "2017-07-10T00:00:00";
LeaveEntryNoOfDays = 1;
LeaveEntryStartDate = "2017-07-10T00:00:00";
LeaveEntryStartDateSession = FH;
LeaveType = "<null>";
LeaveTypeCode = 2;
LeaveTypeName = CASUAL;
RequestStatus = C;
Shift = "<null>";
ShiftName = "";
SystemLeaveTypeCode = CAS;
TomorrowLeaveCount = 0;
```

},

```
{
DisplayName2 = "ABC";
Employee = "<null>";
EmployeeCode = 17227;
ImagePath = "/profile/image/759006c5e4214f0";
LeaveDetail = "<null>";
LeaveDetailLeaveDate = "2017-07-10T00:00:00";
LeaveEntry = "<null>";
LeaveEntryEndDate = "2017-07-10T00:00:00";
LeaveEntryNoOfDays = 1;
LeaveEntryStartDate = "2017-07-10T00:00:00";
LeaveEntryStartDateSession = FH;
LeaveType = "<null>";
LeaveTypeCode = 2;
LeaveTypeName = CASUAL;
RequestStatus = C;
Shift = "<null>";
ShiftName = "";
SystemLeaveTypeCode = CAS;
TomorrowLeaveCount = 0;
```

}]

I want to compare these objects and only 1 object should be added into a new array. I can't use "==" to compare 2 dictionaries. How can I do this?
Please help me
Thanks

**EDIT**

```
if((obj==previouldObj)==false)
                            {
                                 self.arrayForTable.append(obj)
                            }
```

Then outside of the class `public func ==(lhs: [AnyHashable: Any], rhs: [AnyHashable: Any] ) -> Bool {
    return NSDictionary(dictionary: lhs).isEqual(to: rhs)
}`

Comment: I think it's better to solve this from service side.

Comment: They are doing that for a purpose. So I need to handle it in my side

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365654/how-do-i-compare-two-dictionaries-in-swift ?

Comment: @Larme where I should put convenience init(dictionary otherDictionary: [AnyHashable : Any])?

Comment: You don't have to put `public convenience init(dictionary otherDictionary: [AnyHashable : Any])` anywhere in your code. He just pointed out that Swift's `Dictionary` can be casted to `NSDictionary`. Casting to `NSDictionary` is required because you have to use `isEqual(to:)` method of NSDictionary class.

Comment: @nayem But this doesnt work for me. :(

Comment: Show what have you done so far.

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: Consider changing `if((obj==previouldObj)==false){...}` to `if(!(obj==previouldObj)){...}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148427/discussion-between-user1960169-and-nayem).