# Comparing two dictionary of arrays for equality

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the following type

```
[String : [String]]
```

In my app, during runtime I make a request to update a var containing a dictionary of the above type. I also store the same type of dictionary in CoreData.

My question is what would be the best method to compare two of these dictionaries for equality? I was thinking that a hashing function would be best for this but not sure how to approach it

Comment: what's wrong with isEqualToDictionary ?

Comment: @Rei Why would you use an Objective-C method of `NSDictionary` to solve a problem with Swift dictionaries and arrays?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42493627/8294374 check this out

Comment: @maku Do you have an example? == does not work for me I get the error - Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[String : [String]]' operands

Comment: @bigubosu what's wrong with the plain old `==`?

Comment: @MariusFanu What's wrong with it is that it doesn't compile. You get "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[String : [String]]' operands".

Comment: @matt maybe I've misunderstood. You have 2 dictionaries of type `[String: [String]]` surely you can compare them.

Comment: I think I may do something similar to the provided answer. Check key equality then check the array. Or I could hash each array and store the hash that way I don’t have to loop through dozens of values which I guess isn’t much anyway.

Comment: @matt I assumed that we use the latest tools available

Comment: @bigubosu Wouldn't it be better to update to Swift 4.1?

Comment: @matt Thanks matt. I wasn't using Swift 4, had to update OS X and XCode now it's accepting == as valid. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this functionality is native to swift 4:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2430767

A function like this will work considering the compiler will check the type for you and guarantee a key:

```
func compare(left:[String:[String]], right: [String:[String]]) -> Bool {
     return left.keys == right.keys && left[left.keys.first!]! == right[right.keys.first!]! 
}
```

But if you want to loop through it for some reason, a good way would be declaratively.

Comment: It's Swift 4.1 that introduced conditional conformances and made `==` work for the OP's situation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this example:

```
var dict1: [String: [String]]!
var dict2: [String: [String]]!

func compareDictionaries(){
    if dict1 == dict2{
        print("equals")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you are using Swift 4.1. The OP is not.