# Compare equality of Dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

Hi I want to compare two `Dictionary` of type `[AnyHashable : Any]` I have gone through a few answers but I do not understand how to achieve the same.

For example the accepted answer on this link
[How do I compare two dictionaries in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365654/how-do-i-compare-two-dictionaries-in-swift)

Where do i write the given method

```
public func ==<K, V: Hashable>(lhs: [K: V], rhs: [K: V] ) -> Bool {
    return (lhs as NSDictionary).isEqual(to: rhs)
}
```

I tried declaring it in a `Dictionary Extension` but it is not helping

Please do not mark this as duplicate I have already given a link to the answer I am trying to follow but it is not helping

Comment: What do you mean by not helping? Explain the issue

Comment: When I declare the function in an extension of Dictionary it gives me an error to add static to the method declaration, even after I declare it static and use == operator on two dictionaries it does not work.

Comment: You doesn't have to put this function in the extension.

Comment: So where do i declare this

Comment: If you have a question about an answer for another question, you should leave a comment there. You shouldn't open another question about the same, already answered question just because you don't understand the answer there. That's what comments are for.

Answer (score 4):

As per the given code

```
public func ==<K, V: Hashable>(lhs: [K: V], rhs: [K: V] ) -> Bool {
    return (lhs as NSDictionary).isEqual(to: rhs)
}
```

Dictionary value should conform to `Hashable` protocol. In that case, you cannot compare `[AnyHashable: Any]` with `==` operator. It will throw following error.

> Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

so, if we have dictionary as `[AnyHashable: AnyHashable]`, you can compare it by using default native `==` opeartor like shown below.

```
var dict1: [AnyHashable: AnyHashable] = ["Average": 10.0]
var dict2: [AnyHashable: AnyHashable] = ["Average": 10.0]
if dict1 == dict2 {
    print("Equal")
} else {
    print("Not Equal")
}
```

Output : "Equal"

Comment: I think the dictionary values only need to be `AnyEquatable`, not necessarily `AnyHashable`

Comment: I think there is no such thing as AnyEquatable in Swift. Only Equatable is present.

Comment: Oh interesting!

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `Any` object, because it doesn't conform to [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol. You can compare only dictionaries like: `[AnyHashable: Equatable]`