# Check if a Dictionary is child of another Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to compare two dictionaries, the function will return `true` if `left dictionary` is child (inside) of `right dictionary` otherwise return `false`. The dictionary is type `[String: Any]`

I've been finding for a solution but I just found a equal function like so:

```
NSDictionary(dictionary: lhs).isEqual(to: rhs)
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Have you seen/tried this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365654/how-do-i-compare-two-dictionaries-in-swift

Comment: @JosefGrinspun I seen that post but it's about equal

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way but it is one dimensional. Meaning that it searches for a dictionary in the given dictionaries value. I think you could make is recursive.

```
extension NSDictionary {
    func contains(dict: NSDictionary) -> Bool {

         return self.contains { (selfKeyValue) -> Bool in
            if let foundDict = (selfKeyValue.value as? NSDictionary), let anyDict = dict as? [AnyHashable : Any]  {
                return foundDict.isEqual(to: anyDict)
            }

            return false
        }
    }
}



let dict1 = ["bb":123]
let dict2 = ["a": ["aa": 123],"b": ["bb":123]]



print((dict2 as NSDictionary).contains(dict: dict1 as NSDictionary))
```

Output: true